# Radio button remove down correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've two radio buttons with Drop down and I need to put the drop down
in parallel to the second radio button,when we add to the css code 
the following its working but this is not a good solution since if I've 
bigger page with other control this can override them either

```
#__box0 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

there is another option to do that with CSS?
http://jsbin.com/ziziqeyopu/edit?css,js,output
The Html is renders in the **renderer method**

This is SAPUI5
http://openui5.org/
 code but for the question its not relevant since 
renderer is related to pure html/css...

i've tried with the following which doesnt works.

```
.mylist-content>div:first-child {
  margin-right:30px
  margin-top:50px
}

.mylist-radiolist>DIV:last-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top:100px;

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D - Thanks for your comment I've update the question with what I try.is it better now ?

Comment: Not really...could I reproduce the effect with the code you have written? You haven't provided the HTML either.

Comment: @Paulie_D - well Do you want me to copy and paste all the content from the JSBIN? The HTML /CSS/JS is there(in jsBin) and you simple click on it and you can see the issue,I even provide the "not nice" solution with the #__box0 ....

Comment: As @Paulie_D pointed out, the link may become invalid in the future. Please post everything we need in the question itself, so that others can still learn in the future.

Comment: @Mark is it possible to structure the HTML differently? Based on what you describe is sounds like your select box is related to the second radio button, but your HTML does not reflect this. Even if you fix this with CSS, your form will still not work with a screen reader, for example.

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost - Sure I've tried many things.I need the title then line sperator and then the radio buttons and the list box should be parallel to the second RB....

Comment: Please post the HTML and I'll be able to show you a better structure for it.

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost - Do you mean the HTML that in JSBin,its already there ...I can add it to the post but the HTML is not the issue here...(the html of the control is created on the renderer function...) you just need to click on the tab HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94528/discussion-between-josef-engelfrost-and-mark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still haven't figured it out, give this a try:

```
.mylist-content #__box0 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

What you see above should do the same thing as your first attempt, but not interfere with anything else on your page, by:

1. Adding extra application restrictions to the CSS rule, by having the `.mylist-content` scope restriction (even though this should not be necessary, in theory, because `#__box0` is an ID and should be unique on the page).
2. Shifting the position of the dropdown without affecting any other elements - this is done with `position: relative` and the corresponding top and left offsets.

Without knowledge of SAP UI and/or your particular situation, I doubt someone will be able to give you a more appropriate answer.